# How to get a regression line where y predicts x?

Tags: r, regression, ggplot2

So what the title says. I have two variables and looking to plot both their regression lines on one plot:

1. lm(y ~ x) where x predicts y
2. lm(x ~ y) where y predicts x

I figured out how to do the first one but I am having trouble getting the second line. (I know the line intersects and the result I get does not). Any help?

```
x = prostate$lpsa
y = prostate$lcavol

ggplot(data = prostate, aes(x,y)) +
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method = lm, se = F, aes(x, y, color = "lpsa predicting 
lcavol"), fullrange = TRUE) +
geom_smooth(method = lm, se = F, aes(x = y, y = x, color = "lcavol 
predicting lpsa"), inherit.aes = F, fullrange = TRUE) +
scale_colour_manual(name="legend", values=c("blue", "red")) +
xlab("Log of Prostate Specific Antigen") +
ylab("Log of Cancer Volume")
```

I have tried manually getting the slope and intercept of the second line but the line isn't correct because I know it has to intercept at a point within the graph. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you might have gotten the axes confused. When you plotted the second line, you cannot use the original regression results, because now your so-call "y-intercept" would become "x-intercept" in the old canvas, and your slope is also an inverse.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight I agree which is why I flipped the aes in the 2nd line. Is that not how its done?

Comment: @Penguin_Knigh I tried seeing if it runs without my inherit.aes argument and it does, with the exact same result. Meaning the 2nd line isn't seeing my change in aes. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Have you tried playing with the `formula` argument? possibly `geom_smooth(method = lm, se = F, aes(color = lcavol 
predicting lpsa), fullrange = TRUE, formula = x~y) ` Also, your color argument should not be a string, but rather the name of the variable, so wrap in back ticks.

Comment: FYI I figured it out. I don't know why it didn't work just using lm(x ~ y) but instead I found the inverse since y = b0 + b1*x i found the inverse and plotted that and found the line.